# Is there a difference between a property initializer and an expression for simple values in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a difference between these two properties in C#? Would the first property be instantiated one time only while the second property would actually instantiate a new string object every time the property is accessed?

```
public string Property1 { get; } = "Property1";
public string Property2 => "Property2";
```

Comment: Is that proper syntax?

Comment: @easymoney202 Yes its valid for C# 6. (The version that comes with VS2015)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. The first one declares a read-only property:

```
public string Property1 { get; } = "Property1";
```

This is shorthand/syntactic sugar for

```
private readonly string $property1 = "Property1";
public string Property1 { get { return $property1; } }
```

Where `$property1` is some compiler-generated field.

The second one declares a property with a shorthand getter:

```
public string Property2 => "Property2";
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
public string Property2 { get { return "Property2"; } }
```

Which doesn't have a backing field at all.

The second one doesn't actually "instantiate a new string object" because strings are read-only and string constants are interned at compile time; it will simply return the same string instance every time.

In this particular case, you will hardly notice the difference since only things that explicitly look at the property with reflection are going to notice the presence or absence of a backing field. Things get more interesting with non-trivial getters that compute expressions:

```
private static string a = "a";
private static string b = "b";
public string Property1 { get; } = a + b;
public string Property2 => a + b;

Console.WriteLine(Property1 == Property2);   // true, since "ab" == "ab"
a = "no more a";
Console.WriteLine(Property1 == Property2);   // false, since "ab" != "no more ab"
```

(This is a contrived example, of course, but it shows the difference between a read-only property and a computed one.)

Comment: I wrote an answer almost identical in structure and content to yours, after you did. I have deleted it. You might want to show an example of "things getting more interesting with non-trivial getters that compute expressions", which could help clarify the answer.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen and Jacob.

Comment: Removed mine in favor of this. I was unaware of the backing field difference. Great answer.

Comment: @JacobKrall: how's that?

Comment: Great! Anything that uses `new ` would also be a good example.

Answer (score 0):

To add some information to the other answer, when you compile a class with the two properties:

```
public string ReadOnlyInitialized { get; } = "String A";
public string ReadOnlyLambda => "String B";
```

The following IL is generated for the `ReadOnlyInitialized` property

```
.field private initonly string '<ReadOnlyInitialized>k__BackingField'
// snipped debugger attributes    

.property instance string ReadOnlyInitialized()
{
  .get instance string ScratchCsConsole.Program::get_ReadOnlyInitialized()
} // end of property Program::ReadOnlyInitialized

.method public hidebysig specialname instance string 
        get_ReadOnlyInitialized() cil managed
{
  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldfld      string ScratchCsConsole.Program::'<ReadOnlyInitialized>k__BackingField'
  IL_0006:  ret
} // end of method Program::get_ReadOnlyInitialized
```

You can see from the Generated IL that the compiler generates a backing field for you.

This IL is generated for the `ReadOnlyLambda` property:

```
.property instance string ReadOnlyLambda()
{
  .get instance string ScratchCsConsole.Program::get_ReadOnlyLambda()
} // end of property Program::ReadOnlyLambda
.method public hidebysig specialname instance string 
        get_ReadOnlyLambda() cil managed
{
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldstr      "String B"
  IL_0005:  ret
} // end of method Program::get_ReadOnlyLambda
```

As you can see with this version, the only difference is that the string is now being loaded onto the stack as an immediate, rather than loading from the backing field.